# Facebook Open Graph error 2500

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get the profile photos of the members of a group that I'm admin of, but I can't get OG to work. It gives me error 2500 when using a access-token. How should I use the access-token? I have googled a little but are going to get some sleep now so I'm hoping you could save me some time...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/226604429696/?fields=members.fields(picture)?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAPwFhcGIM9XIZBBLJ6RZBTTLyLXt7bicf8nEYLfSDByw2LUGoeH2GIQH5XfycoWZBbhlRp5FCxq9RgQZBaoCglT1ya9BD1GTTkfzaA3ZBEyrpn04U0Qk251XawgT5oaldYpoZAbkoDM7xFf0AW4OPVdsBEnZA6boAZDZD
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by replacing `?access_token` with `&access_token`